# Find the stationary points - algebra

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I've been struggling with this for days and still haven't found the answer given in the book. Hope someone can help.

Deduce the coordinates of the stationary point of the following curve:

$$y = \frac{2}{x-1}\ - \frac{2}{(x-1)^2}$$

The answer in the book is $\left(3,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ when $x - 1 = 2$, but I can't get there.

Here's my working:

$$\begin{align} \frac{2}{x-1}\ - \frac{2}{(x-1)^2} &= \frac{2}{x-1}\ - \frac{2}{x^2 - 2x + 1} \\
&= 2(x-1)^{-1} - 2(x^2-2x+1)^{-1} \\
&= 2x^{-1} - 2^{-1} -2x^{-2}+4x^{-1}+2^{-1} \\
&= 6x^{-1} - 2x^{-2} \end{align}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 4x^{-3} - 6x^{-2} = 2x^{-2}(2x^{-1} - 3)$$

Then $2x^{-1} - 3 = 0$
and so $\frac{2}{x} = 3$ giving $x = \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: You cannot distribute the "inverse". That is, $(a+b)^{-1} \neq a^{-1} + b^{-1}$, which you appear to be assuming in your calculation. Instead, get a common denominator first and write it as $y = \frac{2(x-1)-2}{(x-1)^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You've fallen victim to [Freshman's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream) by assuming:

$$(a + b)^{-1} = a^{-1} + b^{-1}$$

You would need to, instead, find a common denominator and combine, or apply the power rule when differentiating, for example:

$${2\over x-1} = 2(x-1)^{-1} \Rightarrow {\mathrm d\over \mathrm dx}2(x-1)^{-1} = -1\cdot 2(x-1)^{-2}\cdot 1$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{-2}{(x-1)^2}+\frac4{(x-1)^3}=0 \implies \frac {-2(x-1)+4}{(x-1)^3}=0 \implies -2(x-1)+4=0 \implies x-1=2 \implies x=3$

*remember,  $(x+y)^n\not =x^n+y^n$ in general;   this is known as the freshman's dream...